# query_posts ->using meta_compare / where meta value is smaller or greater or equals

Tags: query-posts

I am using `query_posts( $args )` to filter the Loop.
I want to filter posts based on their `meta_value` "vote", sometimes smaller than, sometimes equals and so on....

I definitly want to use the `query_posts()` function and pass my filter through `$args`!
I don't want to use `add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');` and then add an `AND` statement to the query.

I want to use the given functionality of WordPress to filter posts with `meta_key`, `meta_value` and `meta_compare` like this:

```
$args = array( 'meta_key'=>'vote', 'meta_compare'=>'>=', 'meta_value'=>5, 'posts_per_page'=>100 ) )

query_posts( $args );
```

The result of this is:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'vote' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value >= '5' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

The problem of that is:

```
wp_postmeta.meta_value >= '5'
```

It should be:

```
wp_postmeta.meta_value >= 5
```

Then it would work fine.

I don't understand why WordPress adds quotes.

I'm using the predefined parameter from WordPress (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) and it's obvious that this will only work with numbers and not strings which would need to be in quotes.

The documentation says:

> Returns posts with custom field key of
>   'miles' with a custom field value that
>   is LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 22
>
> `query_posts('meta_key=miles&meta_compare=<=&meta_value=22');`

Answer (score 12):

Since WP 3.1, you can cast the meta value to anything you want using the 'type' argument in 'meta_query':

```
$args = array(
  'meta_query'=> array(
    array(
      'key' => 'vote',
      'compare' => '>=',
      'value' => 5,
      'type' => 'numeric',
    )
  )
  'posts_per_page' => 100
) );

query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: This is a great answer - totally does the trick.

Comment: ''type' => 'numeric',' solved my problem
But i doubt that it shouldn't contain comma

Answer (score 3):

From quick look over documentation `meta_value` seems to be purposed for strings and for numerical values there is `meta_value_num`.

See [Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Orderby_Parameters)

**Update**

Did some digging.

`meta_value_num` is indeed ignored for the purpose of filtering. I think they simply forgot to add that part. :)

The issue is that `WP_Query` correctly receives number as `int` (passing as array doesn't matter), but it passes generated `meta_compare` condition through `$wpdb->prepare()` and explicitly marks value as `%s` string. In which case `prepare` forcefully single-quotes it.

So it seems you'll have to filter `posts_where` after all. You can try to just unquote that specific string instead of generating condition manually.

Comment: this usage its only ment for sorting data... but i tried it and it doesn't work. When i saw your answer i though man thats the solution....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend parsing your `$args` array and converting it to a string before passing it into `query_posts`.  When you create the `$args` array, the system will automatically convert the number 5 into a string "5" when the array is turned back into a string.

So use this instead:

```
query_posts('meta_key=vote&meta_compare=>=&meta_value=5&posts_per_page=100');
```

That's still passing the same information into query_posts, but should pass in the number 5 rather than a string "5".

---

#### Update

Since we've now discovered that meta_value stores strings rather than numbers, and you can't effectively do a greater than/less than comparison with strings.  However, after [some more research](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10649) I stumbled upon the query flag `meta_value_num`.

If you run the following `query_posts` call:

```
query_posts('meta_key=vote&meta_compare=>=&meta_value=5&posts_per_page=100&orderby=meta_value_num');
```

Then you should get be behavior you want.  `meta_value_num` tells WordPress to evaluate your `meta_value`s as numbers rather than strings.

Comment: I tried that it produces exactly the same. In fact i even followed the way from function to function in WordPress-Core and the string gets exploded at & and turned into an array before it gets proccessed....

Comment: According to the Codex: `Note the value 99 will be considered greater than 100 as the data is stored as strings, not numbers.`  So `meta_value` *is* being stored as a string ... which is why WordPress adds the quotes.  My next question would be, can you describe how this is "not working?"  Is it returning data at all?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Like i said above no mather what i do i gets wrappet into '5'. Mysql can't compare something on  anumerical level if its wrapped into '' so i'm wondering why wordpress has implemented this function if it doesnt work. No it returns result but just not the desired ones.

Comment: See my update above.  Adding `orderby=meta_value_num` should fix the problem if you're running WP 2.8.4 or later.

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts. But that does although not work. I really digged into this topic and it's just not supported by WP. I will put create a ticket for this issue because it really easy to fix and makes so many things possible!

Comment: *@Joakim* Yes, this is supported by WP.  Read [the ticket I referenced above](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10649) where the feature was added.  Perhaps you can give us a larger code sample for what you're trying to do ... there might be a different issue.