# meta_compare seems to be treating values as strings instead of integers as expected

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, post-meta

Trying to use meta_compare [as suggested in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters):

```
query_posts('meta_key=miles&meta_compare=<=&meta_value=22');
```

Here is my code:

```
global $wp_query;
query_posts(
array_merge(
    array(
        'category__and' => $mycatsarray,
        'meta_key' => 'price',
        'meta_compare' => '>=',
        'meta_value' => 8500000,
        'orderby' => meta_value_num,
        'order'=>DESC
    ),
    $wp_query->query
)
```

);

I'm using array_merge to persist the original query. So I couldn't quite figure out how to use the suggested syntax ('&name=value') for meta_compare and meta_value. Anyways, in my code the meta_value seems to be treated like a string and not an integer as expected.

Here is an example of some typical price custom fields from my custom posts:

- 8500000
- 600
- 15000
- 900
- 750
- 9000000

If it's not a string issue, it could be that WordPress is ordering (DESC) these custom fields as follows:

1. 9000000
2. 900
3. 8500000
4. 750
5. 600
6. 15000

I would like them to be ordered (DESC) as follows:

1. 9000000
2. 8500000
3. 15000
4. 900
5. 750
6. 600

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running? The meta_value_num option wasn't added until 3.0. So if you're still using 2.9, it would make sense that meta values are compared as strings.

Comment: I am definitely running version 3.0.1

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question and my answer there [query_posts ->using meta_compare / where meta value is smaller or greater or equals…](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/query-posts-using-meta-compare-where-meta-value-is-smaller-or-greater-or-equa)

Basically for the purpose of meta comparison value is always treated as string, because it is passed as such to `$wpdb->prepare()` method.

Comment: Damn, so it would seem to be a bug, as the codex suggests you can use meta_compare with integers. Has this  been reported in Trac? Is there a fix/ workaround that you know of?

Comment: Sorry, I don't hang out on Trac so no idea about status. As for fix I didn't test myself but best bet is probably filter `posts_where` to unquote string.

Comment: Right, any hints on how to do that?

Comment: Been doing a lot of Googling, and whilst I find a few examples of how to use posts_where, nothing relates to this specific problem...

Comment: Posted a new question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/how-should-i-use-posts-where-to-change-meta-value-from-a-string-to-integer